# Filtering Firebase lists based nested child keys?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the [Firebase docs for Structuring Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data), they give the follow data structure as an example of mapping users to groups.

```
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      // Index Ada's groups in her profile
      "groups": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         "techpioneers": true,
         "womentechmakers": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "groups": {
    "techpioneers": {
      "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

With that structure, how would I go about querying only groups with a specific member? So only groups where `alovelace` is a member, for example.

Would I do this with a rule? If so, what would that rule look like?

Answer (score 2):

OrderByChild works in this case - below the query object

```
angularfire.database.list('.../groups', { 
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'members/alovelace'+,
      startAt: true
    } 
  });
```

Not sure how the performance is compared to the answer by Frank van Puffelen - might be worse even since it's another list query rather than just a few direct object lookups.

Answer (score 1):

That information is already in the data model. Right under `/users/alovelace/groups` you have a list of the groups she's a member off.

The reason for recommending this model is that it doesn't even require a query to load the list of groups, it just requires a direct-access read of `/users/alovelace/groups`.

Comment: Yes, but that's a list of group keys. Not particularly useful for the end user. How do I get the actual groups?

Comment: You'd loop through the keys and then load/sync each in turn from `/groups/<key>`. To learn why that's not as slows as you may initially think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786